# Proper term for going through something (an audio) quickly

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I know that when you go through a book quickly you skim through it.

What is the exact term when I go through an interview i recorded quickly? listening different steps just to get the general idea and jot down a few notes before proceeding to the actual activity of transcription.

I've looked online but I wasn't to sure... could it be 'speed listening' ?

Comment: I don’t understand the second part of your second paragraph.

Comment: Skim and scan are both good; one more idea: *preview*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metaphor of *skimming*, which refers to the meaning of *skim* as "to move quickly just above a surface without touching it" ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/skim)), can apply not only to reading but to any kind of perception. This is especially true when it's used in the prepositional phrases *skim over* or *skim through*, as the [OED explains](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/skim). In your example, *skim through* pretty much hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 2):

Compared to ***speed reading***, the similar form would be ***speed listening***.

Example:

> LOVED the book. Listened to it on Audible at 2x speed and finished it in three days. Couldn't put it down. Congrats!

Source: [The Rise of ‘Speed-Listening’](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2015/06/the-rise-of-speed-listening/396740/), The Atlantic.

See [more examples](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22speed%20listen%22) online.

Unlike reading a text, you cannot technically change the speed of your listening. You may, however, go through audio clips at a quicker rate by increasing its playback speed.

Answer (score 0):

**scan** works for this - it is not necessarily visual.

> Verb: **scan** (scanned,scanning)  skan
>
> 1. Examine minutely or intensely
>
>    "the surgeon scanned the X-ray"
> 2. Examine hastily
>
>    "She scanned the newspaper headlines while waiting for the taxi";
>
>    - skim, rake, glance over, run down
> 3. Make a wide, sweeping search of
>
>    "The beams scanned the night sky"
> 4. (poetry) conform to a metrical pattern
> 5. Move a light beam over; in electronics, to reproduce an image
> 6. Read metrically
>
>    "scan verses"
> 7. Obtain data from magnetic tapes
>
>    - read

-- [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=scan)

Answer (score 0):

A term used in the review and editing of audio files is **scrubbing**. Here is Wikipedia's definition:

> In digital audio editing, scrubbing is an interaction in which a user
>   drags a cursor or playhead across a segment of a waveform to hear
>   it.[1] Scrubbing is a convenient way to quickly navigate an audio
>   file, and is a common feature of modern DAWs and other audio editing
>   software. The term comes from the early days of the recording industry
>   and refers to the process of physically moving tape reels to locate a
>   specific point in the audio track; this gave the engineer the
>   impression that the tape was being scrubbed, or cleaned.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrubbing_(audio)

A less technical term for the activity you describe is *skimming*, as suggested by @EditingFrank.

Answer (score 0):

**Skip** or **skipping** come to mind.

> [Miriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skip)
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 3. a :  to pass over or omit an interval, item, or step
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1. b :  to pass by or leave out (a step in a progression or series)

> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/skip)
>
> verb (used without object), skipped, skipping.
>
> 2. to pass from one point, thing, subject, etc., to another, disregarding or omitting what intervenes: *He skipped through the book quickly.*
>
> verb (used with object), skipped, skipping.
>
> 7. to pass over without reading, noting, acting, etc.: *He skipped the bad parts.*

Although many sources mention skipping through books, a web-search shows the term is also frequently used with audio/music. The term *can* be used to refer skipping entire tracks (CD and MP3 players often have a "skip" button/function), but it can also refer to skipping *within* a track -- either accidentally:

> [Sonos answers](https://sonos.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/309/~/audio-playback-stops-or-skips)
>
> If your Sonos system experiences audio interruptions such as stops or **skips**, we recommend following the steps below

or deliberately (as would be the case for the OP's use):

> [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1089368)
>
> **Skipping** to the middle of a streaming audio track on various sites causes stuttering and glitchy audio
>
> Previously, I could **skip** through my stream at will, going straight to the middle of tracks or mixes to listen to a few seconds, and determine if I liked the track. Now, I cannot do that on Firefox 41.0.1. The problem is merely annoying on songs that are 3 or 4 minutes in length, as I must let them "cache" for perhaps ten seconds before **skipping** around. Unfortunately, the problem is a game-breaker on mixes that are, for example, 90 minutes long. If I **skip** to a point directly in the middle of the mix,